# How to get the parent router layout in vaadin flow?

Tags: vaadin-flow

With vaadin flow 23.0.x I'm dynamically registering the routes after user login.
This works fine.

```
RouteConfiguration configuration = RouteConfiguration.forSessionScope();
        configuration.setRoute(route, navigationTarget, MainLayout.class);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        LOG.error("Error in configuring routes for {} {}", route, text, ex);
    }
}
```

This works fine, but in some cases I wish to update a few things in the parent/MainLayout instance, based on some values from inside the navigationTarget class.

Is there a way to get hold of the parent layout instance in such cases?

Comment: Have you checked this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67783918/vaadin-refer-to-mainlayout-from-routerlayout

Comment: Thanks. Exactyl wjat I looked for, but apparently used other search keywords... :)

Comment: Does not work in the constructor of the layout, but only once it's attached to the parent layout