# Accessing layout from inside Vaadin 23 view

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin-flow

I'm using Vaadin 23.

I defined a "MainLayout" class to carry the drawer among other things.

In my view declaration, i have the annotation :

```
@Route(value = "", layout = MainLayout.class)
```

In the view, if I try

```
this.getParent();
```

the returned optional is empty.

So, how can I call a method in my MainLayout class from my view instance ?

Comment: Are you referencing to it in the contructor?
Then it's too erlay, do it in the attach handler

Comment: Ideally, your view should not depend on what layout wraps it. Strong coupling makes refactoring things more difficult. Could you instead fire an event (Spring Event, for example) from the view and then subscribe to it in the main layout?

Comment: In Vaadin 14, I had to create a MainLayoutBus to handle things like closing the drawer on page loading or after clicking on a menu. In 23, the bus does not work anymore. So, I'm looking for another way as the documentation is empty on this subject

Comment: This question has been asked here multiple times, here is one version. Please research existing questions before creating new ones: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67783918/vaadin-refer-to-mainlayout-from-routerlayout

Comment: Dear Tatu. I saw this answer but as I said, the getParent is empty. Luckily someone told me it had to be done somewhere else than the constructor. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 5):

## `UI` event bus

Instead of creating strong coupling between your views and main layout, you can use the Eventbus with custom events thrown by your view and your layout listening on them.

You can find a official example in the cookbook of Vaadin, [*Communicate between components attached to one UI*](https://cookbook.vaadin.com/ui-eventbus).

Answer (score 0):

I'd try with:

```
UI.getCurrent().getChildren()
```